# How to add (module with) information of customer in head on index OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

How can I add in my `head.tpl` information with username/customername and my own script in head in OpenCart 2.x.?

I have a form for add my script in admin module panel. It's working fine, post and get the code from base. How can I paste the code in `<head></head>` from module?

Answer (score 0):

To get the customer name in your `header.tpl` file you need to add the customer name variable in the `/catalog/controller/common/header.php` controller file

In the `header.php` file add this block of code within the `public function index() {}` method

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $data['customer_firstname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();
    $data['customer_lastname']  = $this->customer->getLastName();
} else {
    $data['customer_firstname'] = '';
    $data['customer_lastname']  = '';
}
```

and you can access the customer's firstname and lastname as `$customer_firstname` and `$customer_lastname` in the `header.tpl` file.